# Parralel insertion into hive table with non overlapping queries

Tags: hadoop, hive

Say I have to tables T1 and T2 both partitioned on (day, country) and I run two queries in parallel similar to:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE T1 PARTITION (day, country) SELECT * FROM T2 WHERE country='DE'
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE T1 PARTITION (day, country) SELECT * FROM T2 WHERE country='FR'
```

thus, with **non overlapping queries**. I am not sure what is happening in this case? According to the doc https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Locking#Locking-TurnOffConcurrency it is my understanding that the second query would have to wait until the first one is done.

Comment: Please mention your question clearly. Is your query failing or hanging ? Or do you just need conceptual clarification ?

Comment: can you paste your table definitions? also, please specify your hive version and the values for all the concurrency properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that is possible because, whenever you try insert overwrite on a table in hive that table will be in exclusive lock mode... which means you can only read from that table but not add content into the table.

Please refer to the following link which describes locking mechanism in hive: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Locking